# Как подключиться на свой IP с определенным портом?

Tags: python, сеть, flask

Через Flask принимаю данные на определенном порту. Через localhost все работает, но через мой собственный IP подключиться не могу. Как эту проблему решить через Python?

Пример кода:

```py
from flask import Flask, request 

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == __main__:
    app.run(debug=False, port=1234)
```

Comment: Покажите пример кода

Comment: `from flask import Flask, request` `app = Flask(__name__)` далее код... `if __name__ == __main__:``app.run(debug=False, port=1234)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует указать либо конкретный хост, который Flask должен слушать. Например

```
app.run(host='150.11.33.1', port=1234)
```

Либо поставить прослушивание всех хостов.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1234)
```