# Как узнать свой IP в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, ip

Я уже пробовал способ через библиотеку socket. Дело в том, что при создании "сервера" на своем компьютере с помощью библиотеки Flask, он выдает другой IP. Как получить IP, который должен показывать Flask?

Comment: Что такое «IP, который должен показывать Flask»?

Comment: @andreymal Flask во время работы и библиотека socket показывают абсолютно разные IP. дело в том, что мне нужно найти IP, и потом начать работу "сервера" на компьютере с помощью Flask, и найденный айпи должен совпадать с тем, который будет "прослушивать" Flask

Comment: Чем вас не устроил [вариант прослушивать все хосты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417592)?

Comment: @andreymal если прослушивать все хосты, то будет только 2 IP - 127.0.0.1, и тот, который мне надо получить. Если в host вставить айпи, полученный через библиотеку socket, выдает ошибку "Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен"

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Если при прослушивании всех хостов автоматически получается тот IP, который вы хотите получить — тогда в чём проблема? Да и вообще, что такое «тот, который мне надо получить»? Чем он такой особенный и отличается от других IP?

Comment: @andreymal мне просто нужно получить IP, который в будущем будет прослушиваться с помощью Flask. "Если при прослушивании всех хостов есть тот IP, который вы хотите получить — тогда в чём проблема?" - проблема в том, что мне и нужно получить IP раньше, чем Flask будет прослушивать порт, и главный вопрос - как это сделать.

Comment: @andreymal я сам не знаю как воспроизвести это, но во время прослушивания порта, показывается 2 хоста - 127.0.0.1 и мой IP, и мне нужно его получить, если получить через библиотеку socket, IP будет совершенно другим, задача - найти IP, который используется Flask'ом

Comment: @andreymal но если поставить `host = '0.0.0.0'`, добавляется второй IP, который не получается получить обычным способом получения IP в Python. Может быть, найдется какой нибудь способ через Flask получить прослушиваемые им IP.

Comment: При запуске с `host = '0.0.0.0'` фласковый веб-сервер пытается узнать адрес сетевого интерфейса с помощью функции [get_interface_ip](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/6962882b39aa6a2abbeb8e14da212e3d35079c86/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L633-L648), которая использует библиотеку socket (и на моём локальном компьютере она выдаёт адрес `192.168.1.2`)